# MySQL Displaying columns of a group when corresponding rows are of specific values

Tags: mysql, group-by

Can anyone assist in formulating a MySQL query such that when rows with action is "CREATED" and/or status is "COMPLETED" then corresponding updated by should be displayed for a casein?

See attached sample table ;

```
id caseid     action                                status             updatedby 
1 A1000     CREATED                         Open                 1 
2 A1000     "ASSIGN TO ANALYST"  Open                 1 
3 A1000    CLAIM                               CLAIMED           5 
4 A1000    RELEASE                          Open                 5 
5 A1000    CLAIM                                CLAIMED         5 
6 A1000     "ACCEPT RISK"               COMPLETED   5
```

The expected output should be like below;

```
caseid Created By (updatedby) Closed By(updatedby) 
A1000          1                                  5
```

Thanks and regards.

Comment: We don't work with pictures. Sample data must be code-formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, desired output which matches sample data - table-formatted text.

Comment: Okay. I realised that now. Unfortunately default copy in stackoverflow editor copies it as image. Thanks @Akina for your inputs.